# Azure Synapse unable to insert multiple rows into table

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

I created a query that would insert multiple rows to a table but i can't make it work.

```
INSERT INTO bat_report (
  foldername, transactioncode, reporteddate
) 
VALUES 
  ('01202022', '00002762', '20220113-13:54:27'), 
  ('01202022', '00002762', '20220113-13:54:27')
```

based on what i searched online on how to insert multiple rows to table but can't seem to find the error

> Started executing query at Line 1 Parse error at line: 5, column: 48:
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Total execution time: 00:00:03.339

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use ‘select’ statement instead of ‘values’ statement.

insert into tb_test01(userid, username)

select '1','a'

union all

select '2','b'

2. Considering performance, please use bulk loading instead of singleton INSERTS if you need to load many rows. Please check this document for more information which has following details:

Group INSERT statements into batches

A one-time load to a small table with an INSERT statement or even a periodic reload of a look-up may perform just fine for your needs with a statement like INSERT INTO MyLookup VALUES (1, 'Type 1'). However, if you need to load thousands or millions of rows throughout the day, you might find that singleton INSERTS just can't keep up. Instead, develop your processes so that they write to a file and another process periodically comes along and loads this file.